# Missing first row while reading from file - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file which has coordinates like

```
1  1
1  2
1  3
1  4
1  5
```

and so on

There are no zeros in them.I tried using comma and tab as a delimiter and still stuck in same problem.
Now when I printed the output to screen I saw something very weird. It looks like it is missing the very first line.

The output after running `pa.read_csv('co-or.txt',sep='\t')` is as follows

```
   1  1
0   1  2
1   1  3
2   1  4
3   1  5
```

and so on.. 
I am not sure if I am missing any arguments in this.

Also when I tried to convert that to numpy array using np.array, It is again missing the first line and hence the first element [1  1]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
```

You need to specifcy `header=None` otherwise pandas takes the first row as the header.

If you want to give them a meaningful name you can use the `names` as such:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, names=['foo','bar'])
```

Spend some time with pandas [Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html) as well to get yourself familiar with their API. This one is for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: I used np.array(pa.read_csv('co-or.txt',sep='\t',header=None,dtype=float))
Now I have got a different problem, It says could not convert string to float: 1

Comment: Where is the error occurring, reading the file?

Comment: yes! while reading the file

Comment: Check your data, it's reading 1 as a string. I'm assuming it's something with quotes somewhere.

Comment: I fixed it. I guess it was because of having it as .txt file. When changed to csv file. it became fine!

Comment: Good to know. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

```
file = open('file.dat','r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
```

and it does work.

Comment: this is not what he is asking